# How to add cpufeatures to android jni cmake gradle build?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

If I have a build.gradle for an application:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ndkcmaketest.headwayent.ndkcmaketest"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {

            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
                arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc"//, "-DANDROID_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=TRUE"

            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }



    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I add cpufeatures as ldlibs? Adding ldLibs.addAll(["cpufeatures"]) in externalNativeBuild does not work. And neither adding in an ndk block.

Answer (score 12):

Do you have to add this to `build.gradle` specifically? If not, add the following to one of your `CMakeLists.txt` files:

```
include(AndroidNdkModules)
android_ndk_import_module_cpufeatures()
```

Then you can `target_link_libraries(<your target>, cpufeatures)`.
That macro and a couple of others are defined in `$ANDROID_SDK/cmake/<cmake-version>/share/cmake-<version>/Modules/AndroidNdkModules.cmake`.